# Editing an answer - fixed sidebar flows behind footer

Tags: bug, design

Editing an answer and scrolling down causes the "sidebar" to flow behind the footer:

[image: sidebar behind footer]

Appears on my system (Windows 7 Professional) on all browsers I can test

- FF 45.8 (ESR)
- IE 11
- Chrome 53

Comment: can confirm for chromium 57, it's a global stackexchange bug